# "IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array." Save CSV file line by line in SqlDb ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to upload CSV file that have 2 columns 1.Key 2.Value and i to need save them in DB in the Translation table but im getting error "IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array."
Here is my code.

```
  [HttpPost("application/UploadCSV/{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UploadCSV(UploadCSVModelView uploadFileMV, int Id)
    {      
        var csvReader = new StreamReader(uploadFileMV.UploadedFile.OpenReadStream());

        var values = new List<string>();
        var appId = _applicationlanguageService.GetAll().Where(x => x.ApplicationId == Id).Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        List<Translation> listTrans = new List<Translation>();

        while (!csvReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string abc = csvReader.ReadLine();
            var item = abc.Split(',');
            listTrans.Add(new Translation(){ KeyName= item[0], Value = item[3], State = (int)EnumState.Created, ApplicationLanguageId = appId, CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name, CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow});

        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _translationService.CreateAsync(listTrans);
        }


        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Here is my Translation Model

```
public class Translation : BaseEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string KeyName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationLanguageId")]
    public int ApplicationLanguageId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationLanguage ApplicationLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

The View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section>
            <form asp-controller="Application" asp-action="UploadCSV" data-method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return beforeSubmit();">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Version" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input asp-for="Version" class="form-control" required />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Version" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Media Type</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select asp-for="LanguageId" asp-items="Model.LanguagesList" class="form-control"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">File</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input asp-for="UploadedFile" id="fileMedia" type="file" max-size=1048576>
                        <span id="val-fileMedia" class="text-danger field-validation-valid" style="display:block;color: #C23434;"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
        <div>
            <a asp-controller="Application" asp-action="Index">Back to list</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Key,English,Nederlands

Save,Save,,Bewaar

Send,Send,,Verstuur

but i dont need the English because he is the Default language and becaouse of that im making  KeyName= item[0], Value = item[3] .

Best Regards

Comment: Your CSV is trash. You have 3 columns defined, but data has 4 columns. And also that's not how you process CSV files. You can't simply split ",". Read the CSV RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180 on how the format is built

Answer (score 0):

```
        while (!csvReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            try
            {
                string abc = csvReader.ReadLine();
                var item = abc.Split(',');
                if (item != null)
                {
                    listTrans.Add(new Translation()
                    {
                        KeyName = item[0],
                        Value = item[3],
                        State = (int)EnumState.Created,
                        ApplicationLanguageId = appId,
                        CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

It works now and the problem was that the CSV file have Empty rows so i put try-catch in the While

Comment: Check for a empty row instead of creating a empty `catch` statement.